# How to configure tinymce image upload with mongoose express? and hopefully to cloudinary

Tags: express, mongoose, tinymce, cloudinary

[https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/](http://%20https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/)

this is my setup for getting images from a form up into cloudinary, but I can't figure out how to get the images from the tinymce into the req.body or even if that is possible?

Could I use the `tinymce.init({})` or  `tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages()` or even `tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {})`?

schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const docSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  image_url: [String],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Doc', docSchema);
```

form

```
form(action="/add" method="POST" class="card" enctype="multipart/form-data")
  label(for="image") image: 
  input(type="file" multiple='multiple' name="image" id="image" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg")
```

routes/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const myController = require('../controllers/myController');

router.get('/', myController.showDocs);
router.get('/add', myController.addDoc);

router.post('/add',
  myController.upload,
  myController.imageURL,
  myController.createDoc
);

module.exports = router;
```

myControllers.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Doc = mongoose.model('Doc');
const multer = require('multer');
const jimp = require('jimp');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const cloudinaryStorage = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');


cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_SECRET
});

const storage = cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  folder: 'node_upload',
  allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png'],
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(undefined, uuid.v4());
  }
});
const multerOptions = {
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter(req, file, next) {
    const image = file.mimetype.startsWith('image/');
    if(image) {
      next(null, true);
    } else {
      next({ message: 'That filetype isn\'t allowed!' }, false);
    }
  }
};
exports.upload = multer(multerOptions).array('image');

exports.imageURL = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.files) {
    next(); // skip to the next middleware
    return;
  }
  image_url = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
      image_url.push(req.files[i].url)
  }
  req.body.image_url = image_url;
  next();
}


exports.createDoc= async (req, res) => {
  const doc = new Doc(req.body);
  await doc.save();
  res.redirect('/');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a binary image (Base64, BLOB, etc) into TinyMCE you can configure the editor to send those off to be saved wherever you like.  The process is documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

There are a variety of ways to inject an image into TinyMCE including pasting and via a file picker.  Configuring TinyMCE to address this after the image is inserted means you only have to deal with this once regardless of how the image gets into the editor.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the documentation but I can't see anyway to get the images into the req.body and then use them in express. I have my server-side upload handler script (multer, jimp) running, but that only picks up files in the req.body.. I tried this out [https://www.codexworld.com/add-local-file-picker-to-image-dialog-in-tinymce/] which blobs the image but still saves it as part of the textarea

Comment: TinyMCE will post the image (when its inserted) to the URL you configure.  There is an example of a post processing script in the documentation.  The image is not part of the form's posting - its posted when its inserted.  Your server code can process that image as needed.  The editor does not care what type of server code processes the image as long as it returns the JSON it needs.